# PHP-FPM sock failing to connect on Nginx

Tags: php, nginx

I recently switched from Apache to Nginx. The reason for this is because the website would always slow down when it surpassed 100 active users.
Nginx would supposedly help fix this issue.
But at the moment the website is receiving a lot of 502 bad gateway errors.
After checking /var/log/nginx/error.log, I found thousands of the same error which is the following:

```
2020/07/02 14:51:14 [error] 2344#2344: *61933 connect() to unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: example.gg, request: "GET /get_dynamic HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host: "mysite.gg", referrer: "https://mysite.gg/earn"
```

I did a lot of googling, tried out a lot of stuff but I still can't seem to fix this.

This is what I have in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite.gg`:

```
# pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
#
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

    # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

And in `/etc/php/7.2/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`:

```
; Unix user/group of processes
; Note: The user is mandatory. If the group is not set, the default user's group
;       will be used.
user = www-data
group = www-data

; The address on which to accept FastCGI requests.
; Valid syntaxes are:
;   'ip.add.re.ss:port'    - to listen on a TCP socket to a specific IPv4 address on
;                            a specific port;
;   '[ip:6:addr:ess]:port' - to listen on a TCP socket to a specific IPv6 address on
;                            a specific port;
;   'port'                 - to listen on a TCP socket to all addresses
;                            (IPv6 and IPv4-mapped) on a specific port;
;   '/path/to/unix/socket' - to listen on a unix socket.
; Note: This value is mandatory.
listen = /var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock
```

Now, how am I able to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;

    }
```